# Magento Component Manager: Signin Issue :SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in Wamp server

Tags: magento2.1.5

I know this question is already asked but the given answers only for XAMPP. I am using WAMP Server.I am using magento2.1.5.Now my question is i have signin to the Magento Component Manager i got error like **SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**. i have attached screen below for the reference.[image]  Any one help me

Comment: Yes i Know but the answers is only for the XAMPP, i am using the wamp server @QaisarSatti

Comment: Ji check your `MySQL Version : 5.6.x and upper`

Comment: MySQL Version : 5.7.11 @Ramesh S

Comment: @RaviKumar did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

added a Virtual Host for that site, in `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/wamphelpers"
    ServerName wamphelpers.dev
    ServerAlias www.wamphelpers.dev
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/wamphelpers">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: still same error